# accounting number format rounding percentages

Tags: excel, rounding, vba

I am using the below formula to enter data into a new column and convert it to a percentage, but I cannot figure out how to get it to round more accurately. The below code always rounds the percentage to the nearest whole number. For example, 46.07% will always round to 46.00%. I get the feeling it is something simple, but everything I have tried has not worked yet...what is the solution here?

```
    Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[2]/RC[1])-1"
    Range("D2").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Range("D2").Select
    Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastrow)
```

Comment: are you sure? give us sample values for your E2 and F2 cells...

Comment: For example, F2 is $14.28 and E2 is $9.78

Comment: I can see 46.01% in my D2 cell when using your code.

Comment: I don't. I still get 46.00% and every cell in the column is ##.00%. Are your F2/E2 in accounting format before using the code? Maybe I need to convert the data back to number format before executing?

Comment: what if you do it in new sheet manually? and what if you than do it with your code in the same sheet?

Comment: If I do it on  new sheet and execute it...it does work correctly and gives me the "autofill method of range class failed." So it must be because on my first sheet there is some kind of formatting in the cells that prevents it from rounding correctly right?

Comment: yes, something like this...

Comment: Any idea on what it might be? If every cell starts out as accounting format and the new column inserted converts to percentages I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: something with cells formatting, I think... you could try to copy from the new correct sheet add paste-formats to the area of your problem in old sheet to get rid of the problem.

Comment: okay thanks. hopefully if I have to import data into excel this formatting issue doesn't re-occur.

Comment: hold on, `import data into excel`? which way and how- this could be the issue...!! not cell formatting...

Comment: format the cell before you put in the formula?